# Azure Logic-App: Append variable within for each is incoherent

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have built a Logic app that does an API call, gets a JSON object. I have to do some manipulations to get a proper array out of it to generate a good-looking e-mail.

I have done a `for-each` loop to do the manipulation, create the object and generate an array at the end. But the array contains multiple times the same lines and some lines are missing.

As you can see here, the data don't match for a single iteration:

[image]
[image]

Any idea?

By the way, it takes 5 seconds to loop in 12 values! If someone knows why, I'm interested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem may be caused by the "For each" iterations run at same time(or in parallel). When the workflow execute the "Set variable" action, another instance of the workflow may also execute here. So it may cause this problem.

To solve this problem, you can set the "For each" iterations run one by one. Click the "**...**" of "For each" and click "Settings".

[image]

Enable `Concurrency Control` and set `Degree of Parallelism` to `1`.

[image]

Then run your logic app again.